# How do I create a ISO file with Nero for linux?

Tags: linux, iso-image, blu-ray, nero

I have tried to create it by selecting Image Recorder as destination. When I start the burn, it opens a Save Dialog with types nero and iso as file format options.

So I selected iso and hoped it would save in this format. But it broke the file in 17GB parts. So this makes me think that even if it saved the file with the iso extension as I selected in the dialog, in reality it used the nero format. There's no option in the other dialogs to specify the format.

So I ask:

- Is this breaking of files normal?
- Can this be recognized by other programs like K3B?
- Is the saved format really ISO?
- How can I check?
- How can I make it create a one part ISO file?

K3b creates the same file in a normal one part ISO file.
This is part of a series of tests I'm conducting on how to write DL blurays on Linux. Main question: [Problems burning bluray disks](https://superuser.com/questions/855699/problems-burning-bluray-disks)

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it broke it into 17GB chunks.  ISO's are usually DVD+/-R or DL formats, which are 4.7 GB and 8.5 GB respectively.  Perhaps it is using Blu-Ray sized ones by default.  Perhaps there is a preference to change that.  There is a way to associate ISOs with Nero on Windows, so that you double-click them, and Nero will be ready to burn them.  It occasionally has something useful to say about what you are about to burn, too.  Since many Linuces now have similar associations, you might try that.  Other tools you might consider are [IMGBURN](http://www.imgburn.com), which is a freeware application which supports running on WINE, and can create and burn ISOs.  It can tell you a bit more about an image.  If you can get one of these files in a Windows boot, you can use [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/); which has a free demo that creates a virtual DVD-ROM device, and which can be used to mount an ISO explore it using Explorer, as if it were an actual DVD.